# Consuming JSON data without jQuery (sans getJSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I consume a JSON document without jQuery? Instead of calling the method `getJSON()`, I'd like to design my own. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi Vivek. Could you add some more details to your question? What language/framework are you working in?

Comment: +1 Seems apparent that OP wants to know how to make an AJAX request for JSON data without using jQuery. Not that hard to figure out.

Comment: @patrick: Well, it's confused enough people to generate a comments discussion in a mere nine words, so I'd say it was self-evident that it was a poor question, regardless of how capable anyone is of figuring it out.

Comment: @annakata - I suppose it could be confusing if you don't know what `getJSON()` and jQuery are. That could be the case considering the original tags. But anyone here familiar with what they are (like David Hedlund) should easily be able to determine what is being asked. OP obviously didn't understand that the method is unique to jQuery. That is why SO is here. To help people who don't understand something.

Comment: @David Hedlund - With all due respect, if you know what jQuery and `getJSON()` are, then it should be simple to figure out the question. Obviously the OP didn't understand something. Maybe instead of replying with sarcasm, you could leave a helpful comment or answer.

Comment: @annakata - Is it any surprise that OP hasn't responded after comments like yours and Adam's? I'd leave too. I agree that it is not the best wording for a question. More detail is better. But being that the OP is from Pune, India, there's a good chance that English is not the primary language.

Comment: @patrick: when i commented this question was tagged as being about windows 7 gadgets. i found it genuinely hard to decipher enough meaning to be able to be helpful. think of my span-remark as an instructive analogy, rather than sarcasm, if you will. english certainly isn't my primary language either; nor am i from a former british colony. more to the point, we get questions like this one at SO from the US as well, and i never bothered to click through tot he user profile for investigations because i still don't think there's reason to believe that it is the *ability* to express oneself that is

Comment: lacking here. ideally, i think that the amount of effort put into the question should *at least* match the ditto of the answers one hopes to receive. effort, here, being measured both in the question in itself, and in the amount of research prior to posting the question it betrays (if applicable, i'm speaking in general terms). this is not some rule that i stick to, by which i refuse to help anyone who doesn't match that criteria; i still help people out when i think that the question at hand provides me with the possibility. if you think i was dismissive, consider that my brief comment

Comment: @David Hedlund - Sorry man. I think I was more irritated at the others. I shouldn't have been so quick to criticize your comment. Yours was relevant. The others were just noise. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @patrick: no worries, bro. i'm always torn in matters like this one, anyway, and it seems to me that the +10/-5 votes are a reflection of the heated debate rather than the quality of the question at hand. R-project has a posting guide (http://www.r-project.org/posting-guide.html) which focuses on asking questions "that prompt useful answers" which I think is key here - it's really not in for our sake, but for the person asking the question, that the question should be well phrased.

Answer (score 15):

If it's the same domain request then use window.XMLHttpRequest. If it's remote, then inject a script element, you can see how jQuery does it:

```
    // If we're requesting a remote document
    // and trying to load JSON or Script with a GET
    if ( s.dataType === "script" && type === "GET" && remote ) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = s.url;
        if ( s.scriptCharset ) {
            script.charset = s.scriptCharset;
        }

        // Handle Script loading
        if ( !jsonp ) {
            var done = false;

            // Attach handlers for all browsers
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
                        this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") ) {
                    done = true;
                    success();
                    complete();

                    // Handle memory leak in IE
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if ( head && script.parentNode ) {
                        head.removeChild( script );
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        // Use insertBefore instead of appendChild  to circumvent an IE6 bug.
        // This arises when a base node is used (#2709 and #4378).
        head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );

        // We handle everything using the script element injection
        return undefined;
    }
```

Use a [JSON Parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). You can also use `eval` but it's frowned upon in favor of a JSON parser.

Here's jQuery's internal parseJSON method:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    if ( typeof data !== "string" || !data ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
    data = jQuery.trim( data );

    // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
    // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
    if ( /^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(data.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, "@")
        .replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, "]")
        .replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, "")) ) {

        // Try to use the native JSON parser first
        return window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ?
            window.JSON.parse( data ) :
            (new Function("return " + data))();

    } else {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to roll your own JSON/AJAX function.  There are some examples [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg5/).  I am not sure how good they are.