# How can I get json content in <script src="url.json">

Tags: javascript, json, url

How can I get the content of url.json, and cast the json to a variable.
The content of url.json is pure json format.
Thanx

Comment: Do you try to access a JSONP service?

Comment: You can't. It will be evaluated as JavaScript and just vanish in the void.

Comment: JSON is not a scripting language, so I guess it's not possible this way.

Comment: same-orgin, or cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_variable;
    $.getJSON('url.json', function(json){
     json_variable = json;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [jquery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) api? You can use this to download json from an url. Not sure if you can embed some json directly in a `script` tag, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the contents from the url using AJAX and then put that into your variable or use the data as soon as you successfully get the data.

See here for non jQuery vanilla javascript methods: **[reading server file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329853/reading-server-file-with-javascript)**
and also
**[Consuming JSON data without jQuery (sans getJSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238457/consuming-json-data-without-jquery-sans-getjson)**