# reading server file with javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have a html page using javascript that gives the user the option to read and use his own text files from his PC. But I want to have an example file on the server that the user can open via a click on a button.
I have no idea what is the best way to open a server file. I googled a bit. (I'm new to html and javascript, so maybe my understanding of the following is incorrect!). I found that javascript is client based and it is not very straightforward to open a server file. It looks like it is easiest to use an iframe (?).
So I'm trying (first test is simply to open it onload of the webpage) the following. With kgr.bss on the same directory on the server as my html page:

```
<IFRAME SRC="kgr.bss" ID="myframe" onLoad="readFile();"> </IFRAME>
```

and (with file_inhoud, lines defined elsewhere)

```
function readFile() {
    func="readFile=";
    debug2("0");
    var x=document.getElementById("myframe");
    debug2("1");
    var doc = x.contentDocument ? x.contentDocument : (x.contentWindow.document || x.document);
    debug2("1a"+doc);
    var file_inhoud=doc.document.body;
    debug2("2:");
    lines = file_inhoud.split("\n");
    debug2("3");
    fileloaded();
    debug2("4");
}
```

Debug function shows:

```
readFile=0//readFile=1//readFile=1a[object HTMLDocument]//
```

So statement that stops the program is:

```
var file_inhoud=doc.document.body;
```

What is wrong? What is correct (or best) way to read this file?

Note: I see that the file is read and displayed in the frame.

Thanks!

Comment: what is program use from ".bss" suffix?

Comment: .bss is a full disclosure file. Used by BBO to store bridge bidding agreements

Comment: Here is a slightly more modern approach using jQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607452/188963

Comment: Here is a slightly more modern approach using jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607452/188963

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to retrieve a text file (or any other server side resource) is to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX). Here is an example of how you could alert the contents of a text file:

```
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){alert(xhr.responseText);};
xhr.open("GET","kgr.bss"); //assuming kgr.bss is plaintext
xhr.send();
```

The problem with your ultimate goal however is that it has traditionally not been possible to use javascript to access the client file system. However, the new HTML5 file API is changing this. You can read up on it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Thanks!! (added comments to other reply)

Comment: Who the hell uses ActiveX anymore?

Comment: @pthurmond The "ActiveX" bit was necessary to deal with IE6, which had its own idiosyncratic `XMLHttpRequest`. This answer was posted 6 years ago; nowadays you'd probably use the browser-standardized fetch API (with a polyfill if you need to support old browsers) rather than `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I'm aware of how awful it was to do IE6 compatibility. That was all. Luckily us web developers don't have to do that anymore.

Answer (score 18):

Your best bet, since the file is on your server is to retrieve it via "ajax". This stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML, but the XML part is completely optional, it can be used with all sorts of content types (including plain text). (For that matter, the asynchronous part is optional as well, but it's best to stick with that.)

Here's a basic example of requesting text file data using ajax:

```
function getFileFromServer(url, doneCallback) {
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            doneCallback(xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.responseText : null);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd call that like this:

```
getFileFromServer("path/to/file", function(text) {
    if (text === null) {
        // An error occurred
    }
    else {
        // `text` is the file text
    }
});
```

However, the above is somewhat simplified. It would work with modern browsers, but not some older ones, where you have to work around some issues.

**Update**: You said in a comment below that you're using jQuery. If so, you can use its [`ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and get the benefit of jQuery's workarounds for some browser inconsistencies:

```
$.ajax({
    type:    "GET",
    url:     "path/to/file",
    success: function(text) {
        // `text` is the file text
    },
    error:   function() {
        // An error occurred
    }
});
```

---

Side note:

> I found that javascript is client based...

No. This is a myth. JavaScript is just a programming language. It can be used in browsers, on servers, on your workstation, etc. In fact, JavaScript was **originally** developed for server-side use.

These days, the most common use (and your use-case) is indeed in web browsers, client-side, but JavaScript is not limited to the client in the general case. And it's having a major resurgence on the server and elsewhere, in fact.

Comment: Thanks, this works!!

- I'm using jQuery, mostly for calling functions when a button is clicked. Probably I'm not using it enough. I find its webSite not very easy to get the info that I need.

- When Googling for my issue, I found references to Ajax but I skipped them. I thought it required some additional includes or installs. But it works with your example.

- Is comments the only way to reply to a reply on this forum?