# javascript reading file server side not working even answers on stack overflow

Tags: javascript, server-side, readfile

I have the following page witch i made based on the following answer: [reading server file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329853/reading-server-file-with-javascript/13329895#13329895)
but it does not work. And alerts the error. I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

      function getFileFromServer(url, doneCallback) {
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            doneCallback(xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.responseText : null);
        }
    }
}

  getFileFromServer("http://10.10.10.24/DataInfo.txt", function(text) {
    if (text === null) {
        // An error occurred
        alert("error");
    }
    else {
        alert("good");
        alert(text);
        // `text` is the file text
    }
});

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update: My IP address is `10.10.10.24` and can access the link via browser `http://10.10.10.24/DataInfo.txt`

Comment: Does it give you alert(error)?

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: ye it goes to the error part
and im not sure how to debug it, im new to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only load pages from your own domain with an XMLHttpRequest. That's a security feature.

Comment: I updated to make it test on my own domain. My ip adress is 10.10.10.24 and the link :http://10.10.10.24/skysatDataInfo.txt works on my browser but still gives me an error

Comment: Which browser do you use? (I believe that's not server side code as you suggest with the tags) Try F12

Comment: Chrome, and it is because i can access the file on any laptop on my network example: '10.10.10.26' can view it as well

Comment: And your html is also hosted on http://10.10.10.24? (you don't load any local file)

Comment: ye im on mac osx and i put it in the /Library/WebServer/Documents folder

Comment: It must not work if you start the file from Finder. But it definitely should work in Chrome when you load your html from http://10.10.10.24.

Comment: Ye when i open it up via finder it uses the localhost path but it works on chrome on other laptops on my network so what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to enter the URL with 10.10.10.24 instead of localhost?

Comment: You don't load anything with .html extension?

Comment: I do, it was loading it via localhost and didnt realize. Sorry but it works now thanks for the help