# Get json of header included link

Tags: javascript, html

I like to localize a website using json. Want to include the files inside the html. How can i access the json object later in javascript ?

```
<link rel="localization" hreflang="en" href="lang/en.json" type="application/l10n+json"/>
```

I don't like to use the path string directly inside javascript. Will the link element loaded automatically ? Should i use a different header tag to declare the path to the json file. How can i access header tags ?

Comment: will do it like this: <link rel="alternate" id="Link1" data-href="test"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request if you have jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("lang/en.json", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Without jQuery gets complicated: [Consuming JSON data without jQuery (sans getJSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238457/consuming-json-data-without-jquery-sans-getjson)